# picking a picture from a selected group and store it in database - Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, project

I need some help. I'm working on a laravel project , I have a field in database named flag , The user can choose his country's flag from selected pictures put by admin . In other word , users can't upload the images , but they need to choose a picture from the offered collection . After words, the selected image is stored in the database , Do you have any idea or anything that might be of help to me ? and Is there any package of country's flag that could be used instead of adding it manually by admin

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can consume this [API](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all) with axios (javascript) or curl (php) and either populate your own country and flag database or save only a few countries, it includes the name of the country, the flag and other parameters you can consume.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this API ?

Comment: indeed [there is](https://restcountries.eu/), also you can check their [github repo](https://github.com/apilayer/restcountries)